# Setting the model for an Ember controller from a nested resource

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am working on a webapp which has URLs in the format:

```
.../index.html/quiz/:quiz_id/topic/:topic_id
```

And the router is supposed to get the specified quiz, render its title, then get the specified topic and render its title. If it worked, the page would display

```
<h2>Fred's Quiz</h2>
<h3>First topic</h3>
```

The code can be found here: https://gist.github.com/polerc/7806076

I partially tracked down a peculiar behaviour, where the router sets the model of *a QuizTopicController* [line 19 in src_router.js] but then the template is actually driven by *a different instance of QuizTopicController*.

I couldn't find any other questions like this, and I hypothesise that's because I am doing this in a weird way. If so, how would one normally do accomplish this goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's your render statement, you are basically saying render the quiz/topic template with null (topic isn't defined in the quiz template), use an outlet instead, I'll update with example.  Outlet tells ember where to put the next resource/template from the router map.

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="quiz">
  <h2>{{title}}</h2>

  {{outlet}}
</script>
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/EyeRuLef/1/edit